# How can I change the colour of the author of an article?

Tags: color

I have seen I could use the package `xcolor`, but I did not understand how. In general, what is the best, most efficient and simpler way to change the colour of the text?

Comment: See § 5 of the documentation, pp. 38–40.

Comment: To change the colours of sections and the like, use the `titlesec` package to re-define their formatting. For the title, try the `titling` package, or directly in the `\title`, `\author`, &c., commands if it's simple. But beware that, if not done properly, such colour modifications may  also appear in  headers or in the table of contents, which is not necessarily what you want.

Comment: Well, that's a scoop! :o)

Comment: You should know that every time you load a package you also get a manual.  you just have to find it.  I like to create shortcuts (links) to all the manuals and place them in a single folder.

Comment: Usually is enough run `texdoc package-name` to obtain the desired manual. For example, typing `texdoc xcolor` in the system prompt should open a PDF viewer with `xcolor.pdf`already loaded.

Comment: @Fran - Aha!  Part of the texlive distribution.  Also aliased by MikTeX.

Answer (score 1):

In the preamble you can add

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

with one of the following options (according to the colors you want to use): `dvipsnames`, `svgnames`, or `x11names`.
Then you can simply type

```
\author{\textcolor{color-name}{author-name}}
```